# My dad and Share a birthday. Can I say “It’s my and my dad’s birthday?”

Tags: grammar

[image]

An investigation for my and my dad’s birthday party

Comment: The image is for?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to put it would be:

> It's my dad's birthday, and mine too. or It's my birthday, and my father's too.

You could also say things like:
"It's our birthday. My father's and mine."

Comment: But 'my and my dad's birthday' is perfectly grammatical.